# If $X\succ Y$ then is $X^{-1}\prec Y^{-1}$?

Tags: matrices, inequality, positive-definite

Let $X$ and $Y$ be symmetric positive definite matrices. Suppose that $X-Y$ is positive semidefinite. Does it follow that $Y^{-1}- X^{-1}$ is also positive semidefinite?

---

If $X$ and $Y$ are simultaneously diagonalizable, then we may diagonalize both of them to get the result.

After playing around with this a bit, I am starting to think that the answer is "no". But I didn't immediately see how to construct a counterexample. For example, it seems like there is no $2\times 2$ counterexample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) If $A >0$ and $A$ is symmetric, there is some
symmetric $S>0$ such that $A = S^2$ (square root).

(2) It is straightforward to show that if $C$ is symmetric and $A \ge B$, then
$CAC \ge CBC$.

(3) It is straightforward using the above to show that if $A \ge I$ (with $A$ symmetric), then 
$I \ge A^{-1}$.

Suppose $S$ is a square root of $Y$, that is $S>0$ and $Y=S^2$.

Suppose $X \ge Y$, with $X>0,Y>0$.

Then (2) with $C=S^{-1} $ gives $S^{-1} X S^{-1} \ge I$. Hence (3) gives $I \ge S X^{-1} S$ and so applying (2) again with $C=S^{-1}$ gives 
$Y^{-1} \ge X^{-1}$.

Comment: (1) is clear to me. I have studied that result. How (2) is coming? $A-B$ is positive definite, $CAC-CBC=C(AC-BC)=C(A-B)C$. How can I deduce that $CAC-CBC$ positive definite from this? If $C$ is positive definite, then it is straightforward. please help me. (3) is also clear to me.@copper.hat

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan: You need to show that $x^TCACx \ge x^T C B C x$. Since $A \ge B$ this follows with $y=Cx$. Remember $C$ is symmetric.